# How do you ensure that a user is recognised and available for use only when it is verified through a row in the database called 'accountVerified'?

Tags: php, email, verification

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    global $wpdb;
    
    if($_POST){
        $username = $wpdb->escape($_POST['email']);
        $password = $wpdb->escape($_POST['password']);
        $confPassword = $wpdb->escape($_POST['confirmPassword']);
        
        $fullName = $wpdb->escape($_POST['fullName']);
        
        
        $dateOfBirth = $wpdb->escape($_POST['dateOfBirth']);
        $address = $wpdb->escape($_POST['dateOfBirth']);
        $companyName = $wpdb->escape($_POST['companyName']);
        $businessType = $wpdb->escape($_POST['businessType']);
        $truckType = $wpdb->escape($_POST['truckType']);
        $phoneNumber = $wpdb->escape($_POST['phoneNumber']);
        
        $error = array();
        
        if(strpos($username, ' ') !== FALSE){
            $error['username_space'] = 'Username has a space';
        } 
        if(empty($username)){
            $error['username_empty'] = 'Username is empty';
        }
        if(username_exists($username)){
            $error['username_exists'] = 'Username already exists';
        }
        
        if(!is_email($username)){
            $error['email_invalid'] = 'Email is invalid';
        }
        
        if(email_exists($username)){
            $error['email_existence'] = 'Email already exists';
        }
        
        if(strcmp($password,$confPassword) !== 0){
            $error['password'] = 'Passwords did not match';
        } 
        if(count($error) == 0){
            $user_id = wp_create_user($username, $username);
    
        
        
    //      wp_new_user_notification($user_id);
            
    //       $subject = 'Thanks for registering';
    //         $message = 'Thanks for registering. 
    
    //             Please return to the site to log in:
    
    //             https://www.recovermenow.co.uk/userVerification?';
    
    //         wp_mail( $username, $subject, $message );
    
            
            
            echo 'User created successfully';
            
            $veriKey = rand(10000, 100000);
            
            $wpdb->update('wp_users', 
            array('user_fullName'=>$fullName,
                  'vkey'=>$veriKey,
                    'user_dateOfBirth'=>$dateOfBirth,
                 'user_address'=>$address,
                  'phoneNumber'=>$phoneNumber,
                 'user_companyName'=>$companyName,
                  'user_businessType'=>$businessType,
                  'user_truckType'=>$truckType,
                    ), array('user_email' => $username));
            
            $subject = 'Verify your email';
            $message = "<p>Hi there,
            
            A quick security protocol for your new account!
            
            Please activate your account using the link below</p>
        
            <a href='www.recovermenow.co.uk/verify?vkey={$veriKey}'> 
            <p>Click here to activate your account</p>
            </a>
            
            <p>Thanks</p>";
            $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
            $ema = wp_mail($username,$subject, $message, $headers);
            echo $ema;
            
            
            
            
    //      exit();
        } else{
            print_r($error);
        }
    }
    
    
    echo "
    <html>
    
    <body>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'
            src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=AIzaSyD-q6DH3L2eG9pzQYxUZ9YzIzIuJbqJAGU&ver=3.exp'></script>
        <div class='container-fluid' id='grad1'>
    
            <div class='row justify-content-center mt-0'>
                <div class='col-11 col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-6 text-center p-0 mt-3 mb-2'>
                    <div class='card px-0 pt-4 pb-0 mt-3 mb-3'>
                        <h2>Registration</h2>
    
                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class='col-md-12 mx-0'>
                                <form id='regform' method='post'>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class='form-card'>
                                            <h2 class='fs-title'>Me</h2>
    
                                            <div id='imageUpload'>
    
    
                                                <input type='file' id='myFileInput' name='myImage' accept='image/*' />
    
                                                <div id='display_image'>
                                                <div id='deleteImage' onclick='deleteImage()'><h1>X</h1></div></div>
    
                                            </div>
    
                                            <input 
                                            id='fullName' 
                                            placeholder='Please enter your full name' 
                                            type='text'
                                              class='form-control' name='fullName' />
    
                                            <input type='date' class='dateOfBirth' name='dateOfBirth'
                                                placeholder='dateOfBirth' id='dateOfBirth' />
    
                                            
    
                                            <input type='text' class='mobileNumber' name='mobileNumber'
                                                placeholder='Enter mobile number' id='mobileNumber' />
    
                                            <input type='text' class='address' name='address' placeholder='Enter address'
                                                id='address' />
    
    
                                        </div> <input type='button' name='next' class='next action-button'
                                            value='Next Step' />
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class='form-card'>
                                            <h2 class='fs-title'>Work Details</h2>
                                            <input type='text' id='companyName' name='companyName'
                                                placeholder='Enter Company Name...' />
    
                                                <h4>Business Type</h4>
                                            <select name='businessType' id='businessType'>
                                                <option value='Self Employed'>Self Employed</option>
                                                <option value='Business'>Business</option>
                                            </select>
    
                                            <h4>Truck Size(in tonnes)</h4>
                                            <input type='text' name='truckType' name='truckType'
                                                placeholder='10 tonnes...' />
    
                   
                                        </div>
                                      <input type='button' name='previous' class='previous action-button-previous'
                                            value='Previous' /> <input type='button' name='next' class='next action-button'
                                            value='Next Step' />
    
                                        
                                    </fieldset>
    
                                   
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class='form-card'>
                                            <h2 class='fs-title'>Personal Information</h2>
    
                                            <input type='text' name='title' placeholder='Title' />
                                            <input type='text' class='Full Name' name='fullName' placeholder='Full Name' />
                                            <input type='email' class='email' name='email' placeholder='Email' />
                                            <input type='number' class='phoneNumber' name='phoneNumber'
                                                placeholder='Phone Number' />
    
                                        </div> <input type='button' name='previous' class='previous action-button-previous'
                                            value='Previous' /> <input type='button' name='next' class='next action-button'
                                            value='Next Step' />
                                    </fieldset>
                                     <fieldset>
                                        <div class='form-card'>
                                         <h2 class='fs-title'>Login Details</h2>
                                
                                         <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='username' />
                                         
                                         
    //                                   <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='password' />
                                         
                                         
    //                                   <input type='password' name='confirmPassword' placeholder='confirm password' />
                                            
                                            <br></br><br></br>
                                            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Sign up' />
    
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                    
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>";
    

global $wpdb;
$vkey = $_GET['vkey'];
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "SELECT * FROM wp_users where vkey ='$vkey'"
);
 echo $_GET['vkey'];

 if($_GET['vkey'])){
     if($results > 0) {
         $update =  $wpdb->update('wp_users', 
                                  array('accountVerified' => 1)
                                    ,array('vkey' => $vkey));
         
         
         
         if($update){
             echo "Your account has been verified successfully, you may now login";
         } else{
              echo "Not working";
         }
      }
        else{
          echo "This account is invalid or has already been registered";
     }
```

Comment: You should not use `$wpdb->escape` like that, it's not intended for sanitising inputs, if you need to make data safe to put into an SQL query you're supposed to use `$wpdb->prepare` to pass in the query with placeholders, what you're doing is dangerous and insecure. `$wpdb->update` will also do the needed steps to avoid SQL injection attacks for you. It also looks like you've made the mistake of adding columns to the users table, do not do this! All that data will be destroyed when WP updates and the table schema is updated! You should use User Meta instead. Never modify WP Core tables!!!

Comment: Also are you aware WP already has a built in user account verification mechanism? WP doesn't call it verification though, it calls it confirmation. You should also avoid enqueuing old versions of JQuery from the Google CDNs, WordPress already comes with jQuery, and the CDNs don't improve performance and haven't since the 2000's, it's very old and out of date advice, and can actually lead to slower performance in modern browsers

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I wanted to ask a question. You referred to something called 'confirmation', how would that work?

Comment: When you invite a user to a WP install the user needs confirmation via an email address, so WP has already implemented what you're doing here. There are plugins that make the list of pending users visible in WP Admin. Until the user is confirmed they're unable to login and don't show up in the users list. WP doesn't verify users, but rather it confirms their email, that's why it has a different name, but it's the same thing.